# OSMNX graph to distance matrix and DBSCAN

Tags: python, parallel-processing, networkx, dbscan, osmnx

I'm having troubles programming to get the distance matrix from a Graph of coordinates (LAT,LON).

I want to connect an arbitrarily group of points (let's say, 200.000 firms), get their nearests representations in the Graph, created with `ox.graph_from_place()`.

I am working with `dask` arrays and dataframes (`da.array`, `df.DataFrame`)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # OPTION B: Use a strongly (instead of weakly) connected graph 
    Gs = ox.utils_graph.get_largest_component(G, strongly=True) 
    Gs.__name__ = "Gs"

    # attach nearest network node to each firm
    df["nn"] =  da.array(ox.get_nearest_nodes(Gs, X=df['longitude'], Y=df['latitude'], method='balltree') ) 

    # we'll get distances for each pair of nodes that have firms attached to them
    nodes_unique = pd.Series(df['nn'].unique()) 
    nodes_unique.index = nodes_unique.values 

    # convert MultiDiGraph to DiGraph for simpler faster distance matrix computation 
    G_dm = nx.DiGraph(Gs)
    G_dm.__name__ = "G_dm"

    save_pickle(Gs)
    save_pickle(G_dm)

    print("len df['nn']:", len(df['nn'])) 
    print("len nodes_unique:", len(nodes_unique))
```

Some code has been avoided to go to the heart of the matter, then, I've tried following https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html and a `network_distance_matrix()` function using a strongly connected graph `Gs`, but this is so inefficient in computation time. I have seen in the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html) a bunch of functions, but I haven't seen one to efficiently compute a distance-matrix between pairs of unique nodes belonging to the Graph and following paths through it.

I would like to know if there is any way to parallelize this process, and/or make it go through a generative way and not storing all that RAM.

My objective is to provide a pre-computed matrix in a DBSCAN (`sklearn.clustering`) model, and it has to be quickly so that I can kind of *"grid-search"* through parameters. I am a beginner to these libraries.

Comment: @user366197 Speed-ups are relative to your initial machine code and sources, so that if you achieve 1.5x I will achieve that as well. Just I need to know if there is a way to speed-up the process and I'll add resources if I need to. I don't know expected boost because I haven't finished the computation once due to RAM problem. Some ideas?